# d3 time scale gives me a NaN

Tags: d3.js, rhino

I try to render a svg via Java + rhino + evjs + d3. Everything is working with linear scales pretty well. Only for time scales I run into an issue I can not solve.

Please check this small piece of javascript:

```
function Scale_timed(f,domain,range){
    var obj = this;
    this.field = f;

    // print (DATA.jsGetDomain(domain)[0] + "/" + DATA.jsGetDomain(domain)[1]);
    // print (range[0] + "/" + range[1]);
    this.scale = d3
        .time.scale()
        .range(range)
        .domain(DATA.jsGetDomain(domain));

    this.get = function(i) {
        print("lala: " + DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i) + " - " + (DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i).getDate()) + " - " + obj.scale(DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i)));
        return obj.scale(DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i));
    };
}
```

Where DATA is a Java Object in the rhino scripting scope. The output shows clearly that the scale function inputparameter is a Date, but I stil get a NaN from my scale function.

Output:

```
lala: Tue Jan 04 00:00:00 CET 2011 - 4 - NaN
lala: Wed Jan 05 00:00:00 CET 2011 - 5 - NaN
lala: Thu Jan 06 00:00:00 CET 2011 - 6 - NaN
lala: Fri Jan 07 00:00:00 CET 2011 - 7 - NaN
lala: Mon Jan 10 00:00:00 CET 2011 - 10 - NaN
```

I think the problem is somewhere in the d3 scale usage ... so I will ask this with a d3 tag only.

EDIT: this will work very well:

```
function Scale_timed(f,dom,range){
    var obj = this;
    this.field = f;

    // print (DATA.jsGetDomain(domain)[0].getDate() + "/" + DATA.jsGetDomain(domain)[1].getDate());
    // print ("range: "+ range[0] + "/" + range[1]);
    this.scale = d3
        .scale.linear() //.time.scale()
        .range(range)
        .domain([DATA.jsGetDomain(dom)[0].getTime(), DATA.jsGetDomain(dom)[1].getTime()])
        //.domain(DATA.jsGetDomain(dom))
        .nice();

    this.get = function(i) {
        print("time: " + DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i) + " - " + (DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i).getDate()) + " - " + obj.scale(DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i).getTime()));
        return obj.scale(DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i));
    };
}
```

Now I think its a rhino problem, maybe a Date.protype function is missing ...

Comment: What is `range`? The values you're passing in may be outside it.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff the range is range: [0,650]

Comment: And what is `domain`?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff input domain, output range - this is what I have learnd :-) so someone only can plot svg coordinates which are numbers. The time scale translates a date domain to an integer range. see: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales -> "The elements in the given array need not be numbers"

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Domain is [Mon Jan 03 00:00:00 CET 2011, Sat Feb 05 00:00:00 CET 2011] - perfectly date objects

Comment: Sounds like it should work. Do you have a complete example somewhere?

Comment: Sadly no, its a very huge codebase not available on github ore something for now

Comment: Seems that there are in fact some date prototype functions missing in rhino: getFullYear
getHours
getMilliseconds
getMinutes
getMonth
getSeconds
getTime
getTimezoneOffset
valueOf
setDate
setDay
setFullYear
setHours
setMilliseconds
getISOString

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is a Rhino problem, rhino uses java.util.Date as date and not the ECMA Date so you have to convert it by yourself .. wtf .. but this will work:

```
function Scale_timed(f,dom,range){
    var obj = this;
    var domain = DATA.jsGetDomain(dom);
    for (var i=0;i<domain.length;i++) domain[i] = new Date(domain[i].getTime());

    this.field = f;

    this.scale = d3
        .time.scale()
        .range(range)
        .domain(domain)
        ;

    this.get = function(i) {
        // print("time: " + DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i) + " - " + (DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i).getDate()) + " - " + obj.scale(DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i).getTime()));
        print("time: " + DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i) + " - " + (DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i).getDate()) + " - " + obj.scale(new Date(DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i).getTime())));
        return obj.scale(new Date(DATA.jsGetPrimitive(obj.field,i).getTime()));
    };
}
```